# Javascript XMLHttpRequest doesn't read all text file content

Tags: javascript, file, text, xmlhttprequest, size

I've been trying to download a text file using the code below:

```
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', window.location.href.replace('index.html', '') + 'data/data.txt', false);
        req.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
        req.send(null);
```

The request is working fine, except that it doesn't get all text file content. My text file has  135117 lines (5MB), but it is reading only 124079 lines.

Is there a limit for maximum file size reading in XMLHttpRequest?
What could be wrong?

I'm using Chrome v26.
Any idea would be appreciated...

Thanks.